# JMeter counter does not work with variable for starting value

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to define a Counter with Starting value and Maximum values coming from previous JDBC Requests, which are:

SM_MIN=895550691210006042
SM_MAX=895550691212006131

However in the Counter, the Exported Variable Name 'SM' is always equals 0, when it should be equals SM_MIN.

[image]

[image]

Starting value: ${SM_MIN}
Maximum value: ${SM_MAX}

In summary, the SM_MIN variable is not being applied as initial value to SM.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using JMeter 5.3

[image]

so I can think of 2 possible reasons:

1. Your JMeter Variables declaration syntax is wrong, looking at your screenshot is seems that you have `$|SM_MIN|` while it should be `${SM_MIN}`
2. The Post-Processor you're using for extracting the SM_MIN and SM_MAX values from the JDBC response is returning, i.e. if you have a non-printable character like extra space or line break - it will ruin the Counter:

[image]

So make sure to double check your variables values using the [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.

About your first point, I am using {}, it's just the resolution.

<stringProp name="CounterConfig.start">${min_storage}</stringProp> <stringProp name="CounterConfig.end">${max_storage}</stringProp>

I added a BeanShell sampler to parse the values into Long, however I am having the same issue

Comment: This is the BeanShell code:

Long minStorage = Long.parseLong(vars.get("SM_MIN"));
vars.putObject("min_storage",minStorage);

Long maxStorage = Long.parseLong(vars.get("SM_MAX"));
vars.putObject("max_storage",maxStorage);

log.info(vars.get("min_storage"));
log.info(vars.get("max_storage"));

log.info( vars.getObject("min_storage").getClass().getName());
log.info( vars.getObject("max_storage").getClass().getName());

Comment: And this the result in jmeter.log after parsing the variable: 2020-07-16 17:12:52,665 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 895550691211004533
2020-07-16 17:12:52,665 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 895550691212006131
2020-07-16 17:12:52,665 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: java.lang.Long
2020-07-16 17:12:52,665 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: java.lang.Long

Comment: In summary, it seems there is no blank space after the values

Comment: Can you make a try retrieving the value from a JDBC request and assigning to the counter?